# Nested for loop being ignored after if-else chain

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I am programming a MARIE assembler for one of my classes and I've ran into a logical error involving my control structure for one of my functions.

What I'm trying to accomplish is taking in all the data that was inserted into my vectors and then that data is being used to create integer opcode data for display. Yet for whatever reason my nested for loop is being ignored after my if-else chain.

The code within the nested for-loop seems to be working properly aside from this one logic error.

Please note that `instructions`, `hexNums`, `secondPassData`, `valueZ`, and `symBols` are my **vectors**.

For some clarification:

> 1. The If-Else chain is just used to read instruction words and to set `basedInt` to the proper decimal number for later hexadecimal conversion.
> 2. There are a few special conditions in the code below which are marked.
> 3. If there is no special condition then the code checks the `valueZ` vector at `instructions.at(i)` to see if the `valueZ` element is in `symBols`.
> 4. If it is a `symBol` element through character checks, it takes its `hexNums` position and adds it to the `basedInt`.
> 5. If it is *not*, it instead has its corresponding `valueZ` element converted from `string` to `int` and then added to the `basedInt`.
> 6. Those elements are added to the `secondPassData` vector.

```
int basedInt;
int newInt;
int pushInt;

string temp;

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < instructions.size(); ++i) //if i is less then instructions.size(), follow through with the statement
{

    if(instructions.at(i) == "JNS") //sets basedInt to a decimal version of its hexidecimal opcode 
    {
        basedInt = 0;
    }
    else if(instructions.at(i) == "HALT") //a special condition where the number is plugged into the secondPassData vector automatically
    {
        secondPassData.push_back(28672);
        continue;
    }
    else if(instructions.at(i) == "CLEAR") //same as above
    {
        secondPassData.push_back(-24576);
        continue;
    }
    else if(instructions.at(i) == "ADDL")
    else if(instructions.at(i) == "ORG")
    {
        secondPassData.push_back(0000);
        continue;
    }
    else if(instructions.at(i) == "HEX") //checks for the HEX psuedo-OP. 
    {
        temp = valueZ.at(i); //converts it at position i to a string

        basedInt = atoi(temp.c_str()); //converts that string to an int. 
        secondPassData.push_back(basedInt);//pushes into vector.
        continue; 
    }
    else if(instructions.at(i) == "DEC")
    {
        temp = valueZ.at(i);
        basedInt = atoi(temp.c_str()); //similar function as above. 
        secondPassData.push_back(basedInt);
        continue; 
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Beep Boop, program borked!" << endl;
        return; 
    }

    //for some reason the code below is getting ignored. 
    cout << i << endl;

    for(unsigned int a = 0; a < instructions.size(); ++a) //works
    {
        cout << i << " " << a << endl;

        string valFind = valueZ.at(i);
        string symFind = symBols.at(a); //works

        temp = valueZ.at(i);
        if(symFind[0] == valFind[0])
        {
            newInt = hexNums.at(a);

            pushInt = basedInt + newInt;
            secondPassData.push_back(pushInt);
            break;    
        }
        else if(symFind[0] != valFind[0]) //works 
        {
            temp = valueZ.at(i);
            newInt = atoi(temp.c_str()); //works
            pushInt= basedInt + newInt; 

            secondPassData.push_back(pushInt); //works 
            break; 
        }
        break; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it remotely possible that ONE of those `continue`'s is being hit? You realize that skips the rest of the loop body and recycles, right?

Comment: You can almost certainly remove most of this code and still see whatever problem it is that you're seeing. With less code you're more likely to get people here to look more carefully.

Comment: Your debugger is the perfect tool to solve this kind of problem. Step through the code line at a time and you will figure out what is going on.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that the continue statements ignores the rest of the loop. I only used it on those special conditions as they don't need the other operations done to their respective basedInts.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** `gdb` to run your program step by step

Answer (score 0):

If you hit a continue in your else-if chain your main for loop will jump to its next iteration and will skip the rest of your code (in this case your nested for loop)

[continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e3dc2z3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)